# Multiple Members by variable

Tags: javascript, parent

I got this object. It has multiple parents.

```
    object;
    var i=4;
```

What i want know is this:

```
    object.parent.parent.parent.parent; //4x because i=4
```

How can i say something like "i ==4, so i want the depth 4 of parents", like:

```
    object + 4x .parent
```

Comment: It's probably possible because of some code we can't see because you haven't added it to the question.

Comment: How can i say something like "i ==4, so i want the depth 4 of parents"

Comment: Oh, you want to make it work like that? This isn't something you have and want explained, but it's something you need?

Comment: please add `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const obj = {};
const i = 4;

let prev = obj; // Keep track of where we currently are.
for(let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  prev.parent = {};
  prev = prev.parent; // We have to go deeper.
}

console.log(obj);
```

`i` determines how many levels of nested parent you want, and the loop builds the desired output.

You *could* make the `for` loop's contents a one-liner, but I would advice against that for readability reasons:

```
for(let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  prev = prev.parent = {}; // We have to go deeper.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a temporaty variable and store the actual object reference and assing as lokng as the count is not null the parent property.

```js
var object = { parent: { parent: { parent: { parent: 'target' } } } },
    temp = object,
    i = 4;

while (i--) temp = temp.parent;

console.log(temp);
```

If you don't have parents in your object, you could create the nested properties.

In this case, you need to take the last property outside of the loop to assign the final value.

```js
var object = {},
    temp = object,
    i = 4;

while (--i) {
    temp.parent = {};
    temp = temp.parent;
}

temp.parent = 'target';

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Now you're just hardcoding the object... That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Cerbrus, what is op asking?

Comment: See his latest edit.

Comment: yes, i see it, but what does it mean?

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, it could be interpreted both ways...

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't know. I'm confused as well. It's either generating four level deep `parant` properties or reading them. Maybe.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean that you want the 4th parent.
If an entity's parent is at the parent key, you could use something like:

```
let parent = object;
for (let parentCounter = 0; parentCounter < i; parentCounter++)
    parent = parent.parent;
```